# Starting point for an XMPP web client in angular5

Tags: angular, xmpp, angular5, strophe

I apologize if the question may be too broad, surely because I'm new to XMPP.

I'm developing an Angular6 app and wish to integrate a Jabber chat in it.
I've googled a lot but I don't seem to find any clear answer.

Apparently strophe.js looks promising but I cannot find any documentation on how to integrate it in an Angular5/6 project.

Any hint will be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I can't help with the angular part of it, but a few years back I made a somewhat primitive strophe-based client (no framework, jQuery only) that might be a helpful example for that part: https://github.com/cburschka/cadence

Comment: @ChristophBurschka Thank you, Christof, actually I was able to find relatively well documented examples in plain JS/jQuery. What I haven't found so far is TypeScript/Angular stuff. Anyway I'll give a peek into your project, thanks, may be merging your code with the projects mentioned in my (below) answer. Thanks a lot anyway!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I've found [xmpp-bosh-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmpp-bosh-client) and [ngx-chat](https://github.com/pazznetwork/ngx-chat).

The first one is at least documented. The second is not, but I can peek into sources.

May be this can help someone else in my same boots.

Thanks

P.S. If someone knows something better, he/she is most welcome

### EDIT

I'm posting some code snippet of how I managed to connect to an eJabberd (local) server with strophe.js in a TypeScript/Angular (6.x) frontend.

chat-panel.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Strophe, $pres } from 'strophe.js';

import { EJABBERD } from 'app/api/api.module';

var chatPanelServiceInstance: any = null;

@Injectable()
export class ChatPanelService
{
    contacts: any[];
    chats: any[];
    user: any;
    client: any;

    // Private
    private _xmppConnectionsString: String = "ws://" + EJABBERD.host + ":5280/ws"; // WebSockets
    //private _xmppConnectionsString: String = "http://" + EJABBERD.host + ":5280/bosh"; // BOSH 
    private _xmppConnection: any = null;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param {HttpClient} _httpClient
     */
    constructor(
    )
    {
        chatPanelServiceInstance = this;
        Strophe.log = (level: any, msg: string) => { console.log(level + ": " + msg); };
    }

    /**
     * Log into eJabberd
     *
     * @param {string} jid      user name
     * @param {string} password password (actually, the user token)
     */
    login(jid: string, password: string): void
    {
        if ( ! this._xmppConnection ) {
            this._xmppConnection = new Strophe.Connection( this._xmppConnectionsString , {'keepalive': true});
        }

        // this._xmppConnection.rawInput = (data: any) => {console.log("RAW IN: " + data)};
        // this._xmppConnection.rawOutput = (data: any) => {console.log("RAW OUT: " + data)};

        this._xmppConnection.connect(jid+'@'+EJABBERD.host, password, this._onConnect);
    }

    /**
     * Disconnect from eJabberd
     */
    logOut(): void
    {
        if ( this._xmppConnection ) {
            this._xmppConnection.options.sync = true;
            this._xmppConnection.flush();
            this._xmppConnection.disconnect("logout");
            this._xmppConnection = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * eJabberd XMPP message Handler
     * @param {string} msg Message received
     */
    private _onMessage(msg: any): boolean
    {
        console.log(msg);

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * eJabberd connection Handler
     * @param {any} status connection result
     */
    private _onConnect(status: any): void
    {
        switch (status) {
            case Strophe.Status.CONNECTING:
                console.log("Connecting to eJabberd...");
                break;
            case Strophe.Status.CONNFAIL:
                console.log("eJabberd connection failed!");
                break;
            case Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTING:
                console.log("Disconnecting from eJabberd...");
                break;
            case Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED:
                console.log("Disconnected from eJabberd");
                break;
            case Strophe.Status.CONNECTED:
                // We could have used 'this' instead of an external pointer (chatPanelServiceInstance), 
                // but the compiler is getting the meaning of 'this' wrong since strophe.js is not a native TypeScript library.
                // This means that at run time 'this' doesn't point the service instance, rather to the connection itself.
                // In order to avoid confusion I've chosen to use an explicit pointer to the service. 
                //
                chatPanelServiceInstance._xmppConnection.addHandler(chatPanelServiceInstance._onMessage, null, 'message');

                //Setting our presence in the server so that everyone can know that we are online
                chatPanelServiceInstance._xmppConnection.send($pres().tree());

                console.log("eJabberd connected!");
                break;
            case Strophe.Status.AUTHENTICATING:
                console.log("eJabberd authenticating...");
                break;
            case Strophe.Status.AUTHFAIL:
                console.log("eJabberd authentication failed!");
                break;
            case Strophe.Status.ERROR:
                console.log("eJabberd generic connection error!");
                break;
            case Strophe.Status.ATTACHED:
                console.log("eJabberd connection attached!");
                break;
            case Strophe.Status.REDIRECT:
                console.log("eJabberd connection redirected!");
                break;
            case Strophe.Status.CONNTIMEOUT:
                console.log("eJabberd connection timeout!");
                break;
            default:
                console.log("eJabberd: Unknow connection status");
        }
    }
```

Relevant points:

1. Note the use of _xmppConnectionString: I'm using Web Sockets to
   connect but the BOSH version is working fine as well.
2. Note the use of an external pointer to the service. (chatPanelServiceInstance - see comments in code)
3. Install strophe.js like this: in the root folder of your angular project, type `npm install --save strophe.js`

Comment: Hi, Wei-jye. Actually I end up using another strophe.js. And it's working. May i'll share some code snippet of what I've done.

Comment: Hi Raffaele, yes please share the codes with me, I might get the ideas from it. I have been trying to setup my nativescript angular android app project to connect to the openfire backend for weeks with no luck!

Comment: @Wei-jye Here you are

Comment: @Raffaele_Candeliere Thank you

Comment: Hi can you please share  the approach you have taken here.

Comment: Hi @avinashkr. The code in my answer is more or less self-explanatory for those familiar with Angular/Ejabber. What do you mean by "share the approach"?

Comment: @RaffaeleCandeliere  I am specifically interested in knowing how you handled parsing/composing xml stanzas and iq related functionalities.

Comment: By giving user name and password is not safe . Is there any other way to connect xmpp server from client ? I am using Openfire and strophe.js

Comment: @sahal If the "mechanism" parameter is not specified (see docs: http://strophe.im/strophejs/doc/1.3.0/files/strophe-js.html#Strophe.Connection.connect) Strophe defaults to SASL OAUTHBEARER so that the "password" parameter is actually an Authorization Token, not a "real" password (see also the description of the "password" param in my Login() function)

Comment: @avinashkr Hi, sorry for the late answer. My problem was actually how to start the conversation, and my example deals mainly with that. For what you're asking may be this could give you a clue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56022820/parsing-xml-websocket-responses-with-strophe-js