# Parsing XML websocket responses with Strophe.js

Tags: javascript, xml, xmpp, ejabberd, strophe

I'm using Strophe.js to connect to an XMPP server via websockets. Here's a sample response I get when the connected user receives a message:

```
<message xmlns='jabber:client' xml:lang='en' to='agent@chat.domain.com/6665193359253278721998' from='client@chat.domain.com/Mac' type='chat' id='purple42fccc5c'> 
  <archived by='agent@chat.domain.com' id='1557026681122740' xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:tmp'/>
  <stanza-id by='agent@chat.domain.com' id='1557026681122740' xmlns='urn:xmpp:sid:0'/>
  <active xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates'/> 
  <body>
    1
  </body>
</message>
```

Checked the docs, but I was unable to find anything useful on the subject. Does Strophe have a built-in way to extract the data I need from different types of messages? Or do I need something else?

Comment: No idea about the built ins, but you can parse the xml string into a xml doc by using a `DOMParser`. Then you can use the usuals, `.getElementById()` and such or xpath, to interact with the XML. If possible, prefer JSON over XML as the message format as it's smaller and easier to interact with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the connection is created you need to define hooks to receive the message and be able to interact with it:

```
connection.addHandler(onMessage, null, 'message', 'chat');
connection.addHandler(onMessage, null, 'message', 'groupchat');
```

And then, you just need to define the `onMessage` function.

```
onMessge: function(stanza) {
  $stanza = $(stanza);

  messageId = $stanza.attr('id') || null;
  to = $stanza.attr('to');
  from = $stanza.attr('from').toLowerCase();
  barejid = Strophe.getBareJidFromJid(from);

  type = $stanza.attr('type');
  bodies = $stanza.find('body');
  body = bodies.length ? Strophe.xmlunescape(Strophe.getText(bodies[0])) : '';
....

}
```

Hope it helped.